# Mikrotik CRS vlaning and accounting

Tags: vlan, layer2, accounting

i have mikrotik cloud router switch . 
First of all i want to set vlanning for layer2 separating in all IPs (clients) qua all clients can't access to another. For the 2nd step i want to have an central accounting for user managing.

**note** : already i configured usermanager and hotspot without vlanning that isn't my purpose . because i bridged client interfaces together that separating failed .

Answer (score 1):

This is from the [port isolation part for CRS on Mikrotik wiki](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:CRS_examples#Port_Level_Isolation):

With default configuration for CRS ether2 is the uplink (gateway) port for local users so you need to add profile for it:

```
/interface ethernet switch port
    set ether2 isolation-leakage-profile-override=0
```

Then you need to set isolated profile for the users (example here is for ports 3 to 6 only, you need to add more if needed):

```
/interface ethernet switch port
    set ether3 isolation-leakage-profile-override=1
    set ether4 isolation-leakage-profile-override=1
    set ether5 isolation-leakage-profile-override=1
    set ether6 isolation-leakage-profile-override=1
```

And let only uplink port communicate with them:

```
/interface ethernet switch port-isolation
    add port-profile=1 ports=ether2 type=dst
```

This way they can reach internet, but not communicate among themselves.